# Is Class.forName() mechanism needed?

Tags: java, database, tomcat, jdbc, database-connection

Following code:

```
Class.forName(dbDriver); // "org.postgres.Driver" or "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

is / was necessary to open JDBC connection.

I have heard that it is no longer needed with modern JDBC drivers. However I can't remove it in my project, because I'm getting `No suitable driver found` exception. I am using `postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc3.jar`, Java7 and tomcat7.

When can I omit `Class.forName(...)` construct?

Comment: jdbc4 drivers are available. As the java layer between database and java has evolved too (newer types), worthwhile.

Comment: You are using the JDBC 3 driver, it may not contain the services file required for JDBC 4 driver loading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Class.forName() is not needed since JDBC 4.0.

Here is an excerpt from [Java Tutorials on JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).

> **In previous versions of JDBC**, to obtain a connection, you first had to
>   initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. This
>   methods required an object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC driver
>   contains one or more classes that implements the interface
>   java.sql.Driver. The drivers for Java DB are
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver and
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver, and the one for MySQL Connector/J
>   is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. See the documentation of your DBMS driver to
>   obtain the name of the class that implements the interface
>   java.sql.Driver.
>
> **Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are
>   automatically loaded.** (However, you must manually load any drivers
>   prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)