# How to make autmatic popup notification in scene2 when record is inserted into the database from scene1 using javafx

Tags: mysql, javafx, xampp, netbeans-8.2

I am developing booking system. It will have 2 main users. When *user1* request booking for a vehicle, *user2* will receive a popup notification stating that *user1* is requesting a booking for a vehicle.

When *user1* sends a vehicle booking request, the request data should be inserted in the database. In *user2* controller, *user2* should check/read the database and if there is new request received then there should be an automatic popup notification.

Below is my code for *user2* controller to read the database and prompt a popup notification when new record exist.

I am using the [TrayNotification](https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification). But it didn't popup when the app is currently open and running. However, it only popup when user login to the *user2* account, after that when new bookings were made it never popup.

User2 Code:

```java
//-------------------------- get Notifications --------------------------//
    public void getNotification() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/vbms_db";
        conn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
        System.out.println("Connected");
        try { 
            getDepartment= lbl_holdUserDepartment.getText();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE driver_department='"+getDepartment+"' AND vehicle_AvailStatus = 'Pending...'");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()==true){
                NotificationType nt = NotificationType.WARNING;
                TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification();
                tray.setTitle("Notification");
                tray.setMessage("Vehicle Booking Requested.");
                tray.showAndDismiss(Duration.millis(3000));
                tray.setNotificationType(nt);         
            }
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }
```

Really need help.

Comment: Note that `Class.forName()` is [no longer required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391496/is-class-forname-mechanism-needed). Also, if you are using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) then you should use a parameter. The `if` condition can be simply [if (rs.next())](https://java.by-comparison.com/). In the `catch` block, better to print the [stack trace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). I suggest that you try to post a [mcve].

Comment: I would suggest you separate your DB logic. With the limited info you offered, my guess is that you have to use a `Task` or `Service` to run a query on the DB every 30 seconds to 5 minutes. Make a duration that is good for you. I would use 1 to 5 seconds in the testing phase.

Comment: Here is me thinking this through for the testing phase. I would query the DB every five seconds in the background by using something from [JavafX concurrent package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/2423906). If I get results, I would pause the background ScheduledService and use something from the Animation API to display the tray notifications one after another. After the tray notifications finish, I would restart the ScheduledService. I have never attempted something like this. The experts might have better advice.

Answer (score 3):

I could not get `TrayNotification` to work with the latest version of `JavaFX`. I used `ControlsFX` `Notification`. The ideas should be very similar.

Use `ScheduledService` to periodically check new db notifications. If `ScheduledService` finds new notifications, stop `ScheduledService` from looking for new notifications. Display the current notifications using `Timeline`. Restart the `ScheduledService` once the `Timeline` finishes displaying the current notifications.

### Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;

public class App extends Application {
    
    static List<MyNotification> myNotifications = new ArrayList();
    static FakeDatabaseHandler fakeDatabaseHandler = new FakeDatabaseHandler();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        Button btnGenerateNotification = new Button("Generate!");
        btnGenerateNotification.setOnAction(actionEvent ->{            
             fakeDatabaseHandler.addFakeNotificationsToDb();
        });

        Label lblUpdateMessage = new Label("Update Message: ");
        
        ScheduledService<List<MyNotification>> checkForScheduledService = new CheckForNotificationsScheduledService();
        checkForScheduledService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));
        checkForScheduledService.messageProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                lblUpdateMessage.setText("Update Message: " + newValue);
            }
        });
        
        checkForScheduledService.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null && !newValue.isEmpty())
            {
                myNotifications.clear();
                myNotifications.addAll(newValue);
                checkForScheduledService.cancel();
                
                AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
                checkForScheduledService.cancel();
                Timeline threeSecondsWonder = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),  event -> {    
                        MyNotification myNotification = myNotifications.get(index.getAndIncrement());
                        Notifications.create().title(myNotification.getDepartment() + " - " + myNotification.getTitle()).text(myNotification.getMessage()).hideAfter(Duration.seconds(3)).showWarning();
                    })
                );
                threeSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(myNotifications.size());
                threeSecondsWonder.play();
                threeSecondsWonder.setOnFinished((t) -> {
                    checkForScheduledService.restart();
                });
            }
        });
        checkForScheduledService.start();
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane(new VBox(btnGenerateNotification, lblUpdateMessage));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        stage.setTitle("Facilities");
        stage.show();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    private static class CheckForNotificationsScheduledService extends ScheduledService<List<MyNotification>> {

    @Override
    protected Task<List<MyNotification>> createTask() {
        return new Task<List<MyNotification>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<MyNotification> call() throws Exception {
                List<MyNotification> fakeNotificationList = fakeDatabaseHandler.getFakeNotificationsFromDB();
                System.out.println("Checking for notifications. Notifications Found: " + fakeNotificationList.size());
                updateMessage("Checking for notifications. Notifications Found: " + fakeNotificationList.size());
                updateValue(fakeNotificationList);                
                
                return fakeNotificationList; 
            }
        };
    }
  }
}
```

### MyNotification

```
/**
 *
 * @author Sed
 */
public class MyNotification {
    private String department;
    private String title;
    private String message;

    public MyNotification(String department, String title, String message) {
        this.department = department;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("MyNotification{");
        sb.append("department=").append(department);
        sb.append(", title=").append(title);
        sb.append(", message=").append(message);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

### FakeDatabaseHandler

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author Sed
 */
public class FakeDatabaseHandler {
    private final List<MyNotification> fakeDBData = new ArrayList();
    
    //private Connection connection;
    
    public FakeDatabaseHandler() {
        //Estiblish the connection here
        /*
         try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:vbms_db.db");
            System.out.println("Connected to SQLite Db: vbms_db.db");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        */
    }
    
    public void addFakeNotificationsToDb(){
        List<String> departmentList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
        //Use a PreparedStatement here! I am not gonig to demo that!      
        
        //Generating Fake DB data!
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6); i++)
        {
            int notificationID = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1000000);
            fakeDBData.add(new MyNotification("Department: " + departmentList.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4)), "Title " + notificationID, "Message: " + notificationID));
        }
    }
    
    public List<MyNotification> getFakeNotificationsFromDB(){
        List<MyNotification> returnList = new ArrayList(fakeDBData);
        fakeDBData.clear();
        
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

### Module-Info

```
module sed.home.simpletestjavafx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    
    exports sed.home.simpletestjavafx;
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Experts, I could not get `checkForScheduledService.messageProperty()` to update the label's text. I could not see what I did incorrectly. Do you all have any idea what I did wrong? It's my understanding that `updateMessage("Checking for notification...` should update every time `System.out.println("Checking for notification...` updates.